# Super-L can't login_22.04(wayland)

Tags: shortcut-keys, lock-screen, wayland, 22.04

Using the Super + L keys, I am unable to access to the login screen(stays in black screen), however, app is still running in the background since the music player is still playing. The weird thing is when using the GUI Lock option from the system tray, it's working fine. This was tested for both x11 and wayland. x11 works fine for both, wayland is the only one with login issue when using Super + L keys to lock.

Kindly advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a Black screen error or a login loop error.It happens after an update changes some configuration files and so your desktop manager, due to some compatibility problem, does not work properly. X11 is more stable and has less compatibility problems comparing to wayland.

> press Ctrl+ALT+f5 on the black screen to enter your tty.
> (Ctrl+ALT+f1 to return)
>
> To determine whether configuration in your home directory is causing
> the issue, you can create a new user account for testing purposes:

```
 sudo adduser test
 sudo systemctl reboot
```

> If you're able to log in with the test user, the issue is somewhere in
> your regular user's home folder.

[Source:][1]
[1]: https://support.system76.com/articles/login-loop-ubuntu/

Comment: thank you. It works, however, since it's an login issue, shouldn't it be universal instead of only affecting the shortcut keys?

Answer (score 0):

i have the same issue

here is a workaround which allows me to come back from suspend mode with a live screen

install pm-utils :

```
sudo apt install pm-utils
```

launch as super user :

```
sudo pm-suspend
```