# HP Elitebook not wake up after suspend with Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: suspend, laptop, hp, 22.04

I'm using HP Elitebook 1040 x360 G8 with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and found out that system is not waking up after being suspended despite that power is definitely switched on and fans start spinning - screen stays turned off and laptop not react on any keyboard combinations.
That's the last messages in journalctl output:

```
июн 21 20:39:04 ivan-HP-EliteBook-x360-1040-G8-Notebook-PC systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep. 
июн 21 20:39:04 ivan-HP-EliteBook-x360-1040-G8-Notebook-PC systemd[1]: Starting Record successful boot for GRUB... 
июн 21 20:39:04 ivan-HP-EliteBook-x360-1040-G8-Notebook-PC systemd[1]: Starting System Suspend... 
июн 21 20:39:04 ivan-HP-EliteBook-x360-1040-G8-Notebook-PC systemd-sleep[3464]: Entering sleep state 'suspend'... 
июн 21 20:39:04 ivan-HP-EliteBook-x360-1040-G8-Notebook-PC kernel: PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
```

Yeah, I've found out issues with suspend mode is quite common for HP laptops for almost 2-3 years already. But still wondering if there will be some solution one day. Or maybe somebody already have workaround for such case?

Comment: That spells hardware failure to me. Not related to the OS/Ubuntu. Could be a BIOS bug.  Tried hibernation instead of suspend?  Mind that I did not have any trouble myself with the HP notebooks I had in the past. But since using a SSD as boot ... I never used suspend or hibernate ever again. Boottime is under 9s so... quick enough.

Comment: I've tried to hibernate manually... no effect - just fresh boot after that. Seems the only solution to me is disable suspend on closing lid.

Comment: can you edit results of `journalctl --system --boot=0 | egrep -i "suspend|resume|entry|exit"` ? It probably is diff. than what you posted and should also show a message about the why. My bet? the system is too new :P

Comment: Couple of solutions I've used. First try either nvidia 510 with x11 or Nouveau with wayland. If neither works, try the [Black screen error solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1407530/1588972). Lastly, the [Disable NVIDIA systemd services soultion](https://askubuntu.com/a/1406212/1588972)

Comment: This is not related to my case unfortunately. My laptop has Inter Iris Xe graphics card

Comment: Almost same issue, exact same model and same OS. In.suspend mode gets all the battery drained and heats up. I cant find a solution and looking since weeks

Comment: As info; tried to downgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 but still same issue