# Black screen after suspend Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: suspend, intel-graphics, 22.04

I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 onto my new PC. Everything works well except when I suspend the system and try to turn it back on, my monitor is just black, and the keyboard/mouse doesn't work, so the only way to get back in is to restart my PC. I've looked online and tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1044988/usb-ports-not-working-after-resume-from-sleep-on-ubuntu-18-04), as well as changing Wayland to X11, neither of which worked and nothing else I have found seems to work. My PC runs Intel I5-12500 and doesn't have a GPU, so it uses Intel's integrated graphics. Kernel version: Linux 5.15.0-41-generic x86_64.

I'm new to Linux, so any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Seems others are having similar issues, might be this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1968040

Answer (score 0):

To make suspend to work on my Asus motherboard I have set IOMMU to disabled in the BIOS

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I have an Auros motherboard. Will this still work? If so, do you know how I can disable it, I couldn't seem to find anything on it in the BIOS. I'm also running a virtual machine within Linux, so will this stop working if I disable IOMMU?

Comment: @NZ_0 you can give this a shot. [link](https://askubuntu.com/a/1407530/1588972)