# Ubuntu 22.04 freezes completely after locking screen (Intel graphics)

Tags: 22.04, intel-graphics

I suffer from the (apparently) widespread problem of Ubuntu 22.04 freezing completely after locking my screen. This is my system:

Thinkpad Laptop E480

- 64 bit system
- 8GB RAM
- Intel i5-8250 CPU @1.60 GHz
- Intel UHD Graphics 620
- Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
- Kernel: Linux 5.15.0-58-generic

This happens either if I lock it via `Super + L` or if the Laptop goes to auto-lock after a certain time. Meanwhile, I have de-activated the auto-lock. Funny enough, this started happening on Ubuntu 20.04, which is why I updated to 22.04, hoping the issue would be gone. Yet, it stayed.

Running `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` yields `x11`.

I have checked all related stuff here on Ask Ubuntu and elsewhere on the web, but no solution has helped so far. There is a lot of stuff going on regarding NVIDIA drivers, yet I am running an onboard Intel graphics card.

Things I tried so far that have not helped:

- Switching between `gdm3` and `lightdm`
- Switching from Weyland ("Ubuntu") to "Ubuntu on Xorg" (using the settings wheel upon login)
- Newly installing all drivers (`sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`)
- Made my swapfile significantly bigger (from 2GB to 11GB)
- Not a single keyboard combination worked so far (not `Ctrl + Alt + F1` and not `Ctrl + Alt + F2`)

Any help is duly appreciated, I'm desperate. Next step would be to step away from Ubuntu and try some Ubuntu flavour or abandoning Ubuntu altogether, but that I really would like to avoid. Thanks!

If you need any further info on my system, please let me know.

Comment: Randomly, the last suggestion of this post regarding pm-utils seems to have had a positive effect. I will keep an eye on the situation and report back. 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407527/super-l-cant-login-22-04wayland/1407530#1407530

Comment: Locking the screen with `Super + L` works once I have send the Laptop to suspend once using `pm-suspend`. Yet, I have to do it again every session. Therfore, I now have a script that runs every time after login and sends the PC to suspend (via `pkexec`). This is far from perfect, but simply running `pm-suspend` does not help either, because the screen is not locked when you wake it up.